# Select data based on date of id in table

Tags: mysql, select

I am currently showing the last 5 events in my database where WHERE eventdate < CURDATE()
eg

```
    CREATE TABLE venues (
        id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        venue VARCHAR(255)
    ) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ENGINE=InnoDB;

    CREATE TABLE categories (
        id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        category VARCHAR(255)
    ) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ENGINE=InnoDB;

    CREATE TABLE events (
        id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        eventdate DATE NOT NULL,
        title VARCHAR(255),
        venueid INT,
        categoryid INT
    ) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ENGINE=InnoDB;

    INSERT INTO venues (id, venue) VALUES
    (1, 'USA'),
    (2, 'UK'),
    (3, 'Japan');

    INSERT INTO categories (id, category) VALUES
    (1, 'Jazz'),
    (2, 'Rock'),
    (3, 'Pop');

    INSERT INTO events (id, eventdate, title, venueid, categoryid) VALUES
    (1,20121003,'Title number 1',1,3),
    (2,20121010,'Title number 2',2,1),
    (3,20121015,'Title number 3',3,2),
    (4,20121020,'Title number 4',1,3),
    (5,20121022,'Title number 5',2,1),
    (6,20121025,'Title number 6',3,2),
    (7,20121030,'Title number 7',1,3),
    (8,20121130,'Title number 8',1,1),
    (9,20121230,'Title number 9',1,2),
    (10,20130130,'Title number 10',1,3);

    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(events.eventdate,'%M %d %Y') AS DATE, title,
    cats.category AS CATEGORY, loc.venue AS LOCATION
    FROM events
    INNER JOIN categories as cats ON events.categoryid=cats.id
    INNER JOIN venues as loc ON events.venueid=loc.id
    WHERE eventdate < CURDATE()
    ORDER BY eventdate DESC
    LIMIT 0 , 5
```

See fiddle below.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/21ad85/14

I want to show the last 5 events in my database where the eventdate < (events.eventdate WHERE events.id =10)

so where it = 10 you should be able to see event id 9,8,7,6,5 where it = 9 you should be able to see 8,7,6,5,4 etc.

But I am not quite sure how to write it in sql.  I think it should be along the lines of

```
WHERE eventdate < (events.eventdate WHERE events.id =10)
```

but this doesn't work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you need this?

```
WHERE eventdate < (SELECT eventdate FROM events WHERE events.id =10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
wHERE eventdate < curdate() and events.id < 10

updated for the typo: `events.eventdate to curdate()`
```

Comment: @ak85 sorry I had a typo while posting from mobile. :$ But Hamlet answer works well for you.